# Do we want to answer evaporated/condensed milk substitutions individually or close as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, canonical

We have an old, well-voted question about the general substitution situation between condensed milk and evaporated milk:

[Is sweetened condensed milk a substitute for evaporated milk?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/is-sweetened-condensed-milk-a-substitute-for-evaporated-milk?rq=1)

We also get sometimes questions which are about the substitution in a particular recipe:

[Can I use sweetened condensed milk instead of evaporated milk for pumpkin pie?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50066/can-i-use-sweetened-condensed-milk-instead-of-evaporated-milk-for-pumpkin-pie?rq=1), [German Chocolate Cake Pecan Icing](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81574/german-chocolate-cake-pecan-icing)

I see several things we can do here:

1. Decide that the particular situations are different enough that we need specific questions for each of them (no further action needed)
2. Start closing new questions as a duplicate of the existing one
3. If we feel that the old one is not good enough to be a canonical: Edit it to be that (e.g. make it about both sweetened and unsweetened condensed milk) and start closing the specific ones as duplicates
4. Leave the old one as it is, write a new canonical, start closing specific ones.

Which is the best approach and why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that editing the old one is realistic. It's just too much of a change to get high-ranking answers to include what's in the new one. It's not just the sweetened vs unsweetened condensed milk part, but the specific instructions for substituting sweetened for evaporated plus sugar (or vice versa).

I do think it would be useful to have a more solid canonical, even if some questions in the future still need more specific answers. It might still be feasible to edit the new one, but asking a new question might be the easiest approach.

Either way, we'd probably end up with a more solid duplicate target for future questions (not that this is a terribly common one).